# Read excel file with restricted access: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo", had: [EncryptedPackage,

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

How do I read an excel with restricted access? 
Don't mistake this with password protected excel file. I am trying create a java program to read a file where "Full Control" is given only to the owner and "Everyone in my organisation" has read access. Refer to the picture.

I can open the file in windows as I am a part of "Everyone in my organisation"
[image]

I tried POI.

```html
 Workbook workbook = null;
 try {
  workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("D:/temp/table_export.xlsx"));
 } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e1) {
  log.error("unable to read excel file", e1);
  e1.printStackTrace();
  
 } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
  log.error("unable to read excel file", e1);
  e1.printStackTrace();
  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("IOException");
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Exception");
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

 Sheet sheet;
 sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 log.info("SheetName:" + sheet.getSheetName());
```

It throws an exception in "WorkbookFactory.create()"

java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo", had: [EncryptedPackage, DocumentSummaryInformation, SummaryInformation, DataSpaces]
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.getEntry(DirectoryNode.java:399)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocumentInputStream(DirectoryNode.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.(EncryptionInfo.java:102)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.(EncryptionInfo.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentFactoryHelper.getDecryptedStream(DocumentFactoryHelper.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:205)
    at ExlTest.main(ExlTest.java:23)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ExlTest.main(ExlTest.java:41)

Please suggest a way to resolve this. I can even provide username/password in the code

Comment: Usually an `\EncryptedPackage` stream is accompanied by an `\EncryptionInfo` stream inside the .xlsx - as this is not the case with your file, the exception is thrown. This is unrelated to the file permissons. How was the file generated? Can you provide a sample to the poi bugzilla?

Answer (score 0):

The protection we are talking about here is called [IRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_rights_management)
(Information Rights Management). It's a kind of DRM. Microsoft has a proprietary IRM solution that can be applied to Office documents (as explained
[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/restrict-access-to-workbooks-with-information-rights-management-in-excel-3525d8fd-4313-4645-b60e-5ec0e1b9c317)).

Note that IRM has nothing to do with the traditional password-based protection (which POI has support for). POI is unable to open IRM-protected files.

In case the "Access content programatically" setting is enabled, it (probably) means that it's possible to access the file though OLE Automation. For example, you could execute a VBScript file (*.vbs) that opens the document (see [here](https://automationscript.com/uft/read-and-write-excel-file-using-vbscript/) for examples). It might even
be possible to make it save the file under an unprotected format (plain *.xlsx or CSV).

Answer (score -2):

If you can manually read this Excel file, you should be allowed to access this file with read-only permission via Java.

Looking at the errors here, it appears to be related to an encryption issue rather than a read-only permission problem.

As you mentioned, this file is no password-protected. But the error illustrates that you are trying to open an encrypted Excel file.

"workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("D:/temp/table_export.xlsx"));" is also fine but get more controls with File and FileInputStream object.

The issue can be tricky now. There are some possibilities as follows.

1. Verify whether the Excel file has been damaged by Apache POI.
2. WorkbookFactory.create can support xls and xlsx. Try create a new file with the format xls. If it works, change back to xlsx. And see what happens. (rule out a compatible version of Apache POI issue.)
3. How large is this excel file? If it is too big, you can replace Apache POI with Apache POI SXSSF. (for example: > 5K rows)

xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
    </dependency>
```

```
Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(fis));
```

Comment: How would this code solve ths issue? It does nothing special...

Comment: A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system.

Comment: Sure, but how will that make the encryption issue go away?